# What is the visual concept behind squared, boxed or Z patterned letters in logo design?

Tags: logo, branding, symbols

I am willing to know the visual concept or communication behind such logo designs like IDEO's forming or surrounded by a flat square shape and contains only 4 letters or symbols. See the images as attached.

[image: IDEO Logo]

[image: DRNK Logo]

[image: I Love NY Logo]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any particular 'concept' at work. It's just a nice, geometric way to organize 4 elements.

Squares are sturdy and solid, and as a logo, fairly versatile (they aren't particularly horizontal nor vertical)

(Note that the second image isn't actually a logo, but a piece of artwork: http://www.marketingprofs.com/opinions/2007/21492/art-or-logo-how-a-familiar-four-letter-brand-affects-perception)

Comment: Incidentally this is how Mayan is written (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_script#Structure))

Comment: @Joojaa good fact! :-) The way the modern Korean alphabet works is a little like the above examples too https://en.wikipedia.org/Hangul